# how to exclude SVGs with fill attribute from css styles

Tags: html, css, svg

At the start of my project, I added this global css rule

```
svg {
    color: inherit;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

to set the fill of all my SVGs. now I've added a [jQuery rating plugin](https://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) that works with SVG and uses the fill attribute to color the stars. but because of the above code the stars are always black. instead of removing this rule and applying it to each SVG separately, I changed the code to the following

```
svg:not([fill]) {
    color: inherit;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

and it works fine, but I'm not sure whether it's a good use case of the `not()` selector. is it standard?
Any other ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're matching any SVG element that doesn't have the `fill` property. The `not()` pseudo-class represents elements that [do not match a list of selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). This rule will affect other SVGs elements as well.

You could've also assigned a class to your SVGs.

```css
svg.mysvg {
  color: inherit;
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

Comment: none of my SVGs have the fill attribute, except the ones used by plugin, I just want to know whether my selector is standard

Comment: Your rule is correct. I'm just telling that this rule will affect other SVG elements that don't have the fill attribute even if you don't want to style them.